# Velocity Template Alternatives

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

My question is regarding this thread:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18368

> For Spring 5, we are strategically moving away from traditional
> template-based web views in general. Even just for that reason alone,
> we are not going to introduce support for any new template engine
> generations but rather focus on other areas (Jackson integration,
> JavaScript templates, etc). FWIW, we are going to keep supporting
> FreeMarker as a sort of reference - in classic Servlet MVC as well as
> Spring's new reactive web support -, including our generic base
> classes for template-based views which other support classes may
> derive from (like the Velocity 1.x based view classes do right now).

I am working on migrating an application from WebSphere to Tomcat and Ant to Maven. Along the way we decided to make an update to Spring and few other stuff to newer versions. The application dates back to 2005s. So not all of it, is the latest and greatest.

One of the road blocks is, migrating to Spring 5.0, dropped support for Velocity. A tool which our application uses extensively. We were using Spring 2.8 or something! :)

Now, I see the statements:

> For Spring 5, we are strategically moving away from traditional
> template-based web views
>
> FWIW, we are going to keep supporting FreeMarker as a sort of
> reference

I gather, in the near future, even this will fall by the wayside. I just wanted to know if there are any practical alternatives now that we can migrate to and something that is a wee bit future proof. Don't want to migrate to FreeMaker if its days are numbered too.

Comment: They're not deprecating velocity, they're just removing some spring-provided support library that wasn't getting maintained. and they're not adding more templating libraries, but working on improving support for REST and single-page applications. so probably not a lot to worry about here.

Comment: One of the packages `org.springframework.ui.velocity.*` is completely gone. Don't know how to use instead of that. If you can point me in that direction it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Like Nathan Hugues said, you can still use *Velocity*, it's just that Spring dropped a support package for it.

As mentionned in the blog post you quoted, *Thymeleaf* has Spring support, it is just provided by the Thymeleaf team, not the Spring team. And from now, they let the Velocity team handle the Spring integration if they want to.

If you want to migrate to a new template engine, this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-template-engines) should be useful.

Comment: For now we have decided to stick to velocity and make all new template requirement in some other tool, when the need arises. I found this dependency `
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-velocity-support</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.7</version>
</dependency>`, which has all the missing classes bundled into one. lets hope it works. If not, its back to the drawing-board.